# Ubuntu 13.10 does not boot after successful installation: 'all boot options are tried'

Tags: boot, 13.10, amd-graphics

I am new to Ubuntu and Linux.

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit on my new Samsung Ativ (4 GB memory / Quad Core 1.4 GHz processor / AMD Radeon HD8250 graphic card / 128 G SSD).

The first time all went well, except for graphics issues, which I was able to fix by installing fglrx.

After an update something went wrong, I couldn't log in anymore and could only work with a guest account. After trying to fix that, I decided to reinstall Ubuntu.

This won't work, as after installation and rebooting all I see is `All boot options are tried, press F4 for Recovery mode`. Pressing <kbd>F4</kbd> didn't change anything. If I reinstall, I see that Ubuntu is installed and am asked if I want to reinstall, install alongside 13.10 or erase and install.

After installing, the whole thing repeats, "all boot options are tried" after rebooting.

Pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> while booting didn't help.

What went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Its a problem in your ubuntu cd installation. 
Try to download and burns again then install your ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Not trying to be funny, but you need to take out the flash drive (USB) or CD after installing.

Apart from that, it would be wiser if you made another live USB or disk and tried again.

EDIT: Just putting the solution here as well:

To fully re-install Ubuntu,

1. Choose `Something Else` from the installation menu.
2. Format everything (except the `Windows` or `OS X` partitions; they're optional)
3. Install

Comment: Thanks, but I remove the installation USB, of course. And I already tried to instaal with a different USB...

Comment: When you are asked to install ubuntu again, choose `Something Else`  and format your entire hard drive (If you have a `Windows` partition, you may skip that). Then install.

Comment: Thanks. I followed your advise on making another live usb. I tried the xubuntu 13.10 32 bit, everything works now. I still had to solve the low graphics mode by installing fglrx. But I still have the impression that the fglrx situation is not something normal to the system. Is it wiser to use xorg xserver?

Comment: If you are going to extensively use your `dedicated GPU`, use `flgrx`. `Xorg xserver`, however is far more stable. It's really up to you. Personally, I have an Nvidia card, and the nvidia drivers are very poor, so I stick to open source tested alternatives.

[See](http://askubuntu.com/questions/279736/x-org-x-server-driver-or-amd-proprietary-driver)